# What is the proper method for having a Win10 installation, an Ubuntu Installation with Secureboot enabled [locked bios]?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, secure-boot

I already installed ubuntu successfully on my notebook. I have two physical drives, one SSD and one HDD. The BIOS is locked and the SecureBoot is turned on with no way to turn it off.

I previously had Windows on the HDD, recently reinstalled it to the SSD (Windows boot manager is still on the HDD). I installed Ubuntu (95 GB Partition and a 5 GB swap) to a separate partition I made on the HDD. The bootloader is on the SSD (I was worried about deleting the windows boot manager and borking windows).

The problem is that I can't really see the SSD all the time in my bios an thus can not boot into linux. I'd like to ideally have just grub handle booting windows or linux for me (chose on startup). What is the best way to set it up this way with minimal danger? I am worried about getting a system where I can't run either operating system (or worse).

Has anyone ever done anything similar and would have some advice or maybe even a guide?

Comment: Why do you have a locked BIOS? Locked BIOSes complicate multi-boots enormously. Regardless, there generally isn't a "proper" way to dual boot. What do you mean "can't always see the SSD all the time in the BIOS"?

Comment: Hi Patrick. I have seen the SSD one single time under boot options. It does no longer show up, only the HDD. I have a locked bios because my notebook was shipped to me this way and I do not know how to unlock it (E5-573). I just tried installing Ubuntu a few times, trying to install the bootloader to both hard drives, trying to overwrite the windows bootloader but it doesn't seem to work. Quite frustrating... I don't know why but the windows boot loader doesn't get deleted, even if completely formatting the HDD it still boots from the windows boot loader on the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Under EFI, the boot options list you see is not a good indicator of whether the firmware can access a given disk. The EFI's boot order list can contain boot information based on BIOS-mode boot loaders (typically corresponding to specific devices), EFI boot files, fallback EFI boot files (typically corresponding to specific devices), BIOS-mode or EFI-mode option ROMs in plug-in cards, and more. Some of these options are automatically generated by the firmware, but others are created by OS installation programs or by you (using tools like Ubuntu's `efibootmgr`). Options you set in the firmware (to activate network booting, for instance) can add or delete boot options. Note that a disk device might be perfectly accessible to the firmware but the EFI's boot list might not mention it because that disk device has no boot loader that the firmware can detect (or none that's been recorded in the NVRAM).

That said, there *are* cases where the firmware can be slow to recognize a disk device, or where it may be completely inaccessible to the firmware because the firmware may lack drivers. Based on your description, the first of these cases *might* be happening to you, but it's at least as likely that you're not seeing your SSD in the boot list simply because it has no boot loader(s) installed on it.

As a precaution against rendering your computer unbootable, you may want to prepare a USB flash drive or CD-R with my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) Download links with images for both media types are present on that page. Note, however, that the stock rEFInd images will not work with Secure Boot enabled. To add Secure Boot support, you must jump through extra hoops, as described in the [rEFInd Secure Boot documentation.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) Alternatively, you can temporarily disable Secure Boot if you need to use rEFInd to boot your computer. (It's almost always possible to disable Secure Boot. The option to do so may be very obscure or poorly identified, but it's almost always available.)

With that in mind, you can have one or more [EFI System Partitions (ESPs),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) located on one or both of your disks. Complicating this is the fact that Ubuntu's GRUB configuration requires that GRUB be able to read both its configuration file (`grub.cfg`) and the Linux kernel, both of which go in `/boot` on Ubuntu. Thus, if there *is* a problem with accessing one disk from the EFI, and if `/boot` is on the problem disk, GRUB won't work correctly. You can guard against this possibility by creating a separate `/boot` partition (make it at least 500 MiB) on the disk that's safer, from an EFI accessibility point of view. Likewise, the Windows boot loader must be able to access the Windows partition.

In sum, if you have any doubts about the ability of your EFI to read one of your disks, you should put your ESP(s), Ubuntu `/boot` partition, and Windows `C:` partition on the "safe" disk. You can then use the disk that may pose problems for the Ubuntu root (`/`), Ubuntu `/home`, swap, Windows data, and anything else.